# Getting "OverflowError: int too big to convert" while reading sas file into pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, overflow

I am trying to load the   "x.sas7bdat"  file using pandas read. (Python 3)

```
import pandas as pd
x_df = pd.read_sas(r"x.sas7bdat")
```

I am getting the following error.

> "OverflowError: int too big to convert"

I tired to read the same file in binary format.

```
f=(r"x.sas7bdat", 'rb')
```

I am not getting any error.

I have tried

> ('utf-8', 'Latin1', 'cp1252')

encoding while reading into the pandas data frame.All are giving the same error

> "Int too big to convert "
>   error.

Is there a way to find where particular in data this problem is arising ?
Any  fix or way around for this problem ?

Comment: Share file contents?

Comment: Nehal , sorry .  I couldn't share the file contents. They are part of the work. If possible can you tell what I should be looking for in the files.

Comment: Share sample file contents?

Comment: I was able to convert the sas data files to csv files. I dont have any issue reading those files.

Comment: Thanks for the help